# schema.org Residence lacks some specialisations

Tags: microdata

After reviewing http://schema.org/Residence and the Specialisation under it, it seems that the wording is very west oriented. Especially in the sense of representing `Condo` buildings? and as an extreme example of "Village"

I am unsure if using `ApartmentComplex` to represent `Condo` is the correct approach, since the term `Apartment` is almost exclusively used for rental property in the west. By classifying a Condo building as `ApartmentComplex` would set bias towards rental queries as opposed to sale queries.

Using the term Residence to describe a Condo or Village's is acceptable? What is the benefit of describing using the specialised terms?

Comment: I always thought the origins of condominiums to be apartments you can own. I'm not sure ApartmentComplex is incorrect but I understand why you feel that way.

Comment: hi guys, i appreciate the answers. i need to do some research before accepting an answer. thanks again i +1 both of you already :)

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using specific is *supposed to be* the additional field attributed to them.

For a `Condo`, it might be 'safer' to use `Residence` or `Place` vs `ApartmentComplex` unless you **specifically need** an *attribute* that appears in `ApartmentComplex` and not in it's parents i.e. `Place`.

`Place` should cover most locations and since these two *specific* items in your example merely extend `Place`, they are in fact unnecessary. The only property that is entrenched in these item types is the `containedIn` field (which takes a `Place`), but neither have `Residence` nor `ApartmentComplex`specific attributes.

Having super specific type is honestly one of the most short sighted and foolish things about schema.org. For your case, all three items are essentially the same as `Place`.

A good rule of thumb is to read the description of the schema item type and sees if it represents your item. If it accurately describes your `thing`, then use that. If not, defer to it's parent (et all, until you get to `thing`)

I assume `The place where a person lives.` describes your item well, therefore `Residence` is fine.

Comment: thanks for your excellent explanation. However in the context of promoting `PlacesToLive` rent or sale. Does having `Residence` plays an important role over `Place` ? or did you mean to say all 3 things same as `Residence` ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, an [`ApartmentComplex`](http://schema.org/ApartmentComplex) does not represent a single apartment/condo, but the whole building consisting of several apartments/condos.

(In the same sense, [`GatedResidenceCommunity`](http://schema.org/GatedResidenceCommunity) is for the whole community, not a single residence inside of that community.)

So if you want to represent a single apartment/condo, you should use [`Residence`](http://schema.org/Residence).

You could use other vocabularies (in addition) to specify more detailed types, e.g. [`Condominium`](http://www.productontology.org/id/Condominium) from the Product Types Ontology.

Comment: hi thanks for the input and mentioning about `Product Types Ontology`

Comment: hi @unor can you provide some reference that Product Type Ontology is supported and recognised by Google?

Comment: @DevZer0: I don’t know if, or to which extent, Google Search makes use of the classes from the Product Types Ontology. -- (On https://developers.google.com/structured-data/ Google references only the vocabularies Schema.org and Data-Vocabulary.org, but that doesn’t necessarily mean that they don’t make some use of other vocabularies, too.)